# Can't make two 1:1 relations in one model in Prisma. Ambiguous relation detected

Tags: orm, schema, database-schema, prisma, prisma2

I'm trying to make two 1:1 relations in one model in Prisma ORM, but got following error:

> Error validating model "Person": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `placeOfBirth` and `placeOfDeath` in model `Person` both refer to `Place`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation(<name>)`.

My prisma schema:

```
model Place {
    id              Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
    name            String
    persons         Person[]
}

model Person {
    id              Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
    name            String
    placeOfBirthId  Int
    placeOfDeathId  Int
  placeOfBirth    Place   @relation(fields: [placeOfBirthId], references: [id])
    placeOfDeath    Place   @relation(fields: [placeOfDeathId], references: [id])
}
```

Totally don't get it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to add a `name` field to `placeOfBirth` and `placeOfDeath`. Then use these names to reference both of them in the `Place` model.

```
model Place {
  id     Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name   String
  Births Person[] @relation("Births")
  Deaths Person[] @relation("Deaths")
}

model Person {
  id             Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name           String
  placeOfBirthId Int
  placeOfDeathId Int
  placeOfBirth   Place  @relation("Births", fields: [placeOfBirthId], references: [id])
  placeOfDeath   Place  @relation("Deaths", fields: [placeOfDeathId], references: [id])
}
```